# Using a Custom Filter in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am relatively new to AngularJs and I came across a problem when using OrderBy: in regards to sorting objects, so I borrowed a custom filter to sort objects but I am not understanding what the correct syntax to use this Filter appropriately as it wont sort by the Key in the object I want it to:

**js:**

```
<tbody ng-repeat="(field, profile) in currentSample.dsProfile | orderByObject:'profile[display-name]' track by $index">
            <tr ng-style="$index % 2 === 0 && {'background-color': '#ffffff'} ||
                          $index % 2 === 1 && {'background-color': '#f9f9f9'}">
                <td style="width: 19%; margin: 2px; padding: 0px;"
                    ng-style="profile['shown-in-details'] == true && {'background-color': 'gold'} ||
                              profile['shown-in-details'] == false && {'background-color': 'transparent'}">
                    <span class="btn-property"
                          ng-click="showInGenericDetails(currentSample, field)"
                          uib-tooltip="{{field}}"
                          tooltip-placement="right">
                        <b>{{profile["display-name"]}}</b>
                    </span>
```

**json**[image]

**Filter:**

```
app.filter('orderByObject', function() {
                return function(items, field, reverse) {
                    var filtered = [];
                    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
                        filtered.push(item);
                    });
                    filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
                        return (a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1);
                    });
                    if(reverse) filtered.reverse();
                    return filtered;
                };
            });
```

**without filter**

```
<table id="data-sources-table" class="table drag-drop">
                            <tbody ng-repeat="(field, profile) in currentSchema.sProfile | orderBy:PROPERTY track by $index">
                            <tr ng-style="$index %2 === 0 && {'background-color': '#ffffff'} ||
                                              $index %2 === 1 && {'background-color': '#f9f9f9'}">
                                <td style="width: 180px">
                                        <span class="btn-property">
                                            <b>{{field}}</b>
```

Comment: for `field` use name of field(property) only

Comment: so just '[display-name]'

Comment: no...there is no `[]` in any of the property names

Comment: angular.js:12520 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: orderByObjectFilterProvider <- orderByObjectFilter
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=orderByObjectFilterProvider%20%3C-"<!-- ngRepeat: (field, profile) in currentSample.dsProfile | orderByObject:'display-name' track by $index -->"rderByObjectFilter

Comment: Create demo that reproduces this

Comment: not sure how that will work with Objects....

Comment: Well, I can't provide a more expandable answer since you didn't provide your `JSON/array` structure. Edit your question putting them and I can help.

Comment: sorry it fails, it does not sort anything

Comment: what do you mean by structure? JSON structure? HTML structure?

Comment: @developer033 `orderBy` does not work with objects;  in previous angular releases it just didn't work, but in newer releases it actually throws an error. (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).  This is because JavaScript does not define an order for keys within an object.

Comment: @Claies, that's why I'm asking for him to provide his structure.. since I even don't know what he's trying to do.

Comment: bottom line the custom filter works for my objects on one of my tables however on the other it just assigns them a numeric number

Comment: so what is the appropriate solution to this problem?

Comment: @user2402107, I remember to add some more things to my answer, take a look, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't use [**orderBy**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) directly because this `filter` needs to filter a collection, you should *parse* your items to a collection, something like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var testObj = {  
     "obj1":{  
        "id":1,
        "title":"Title1"
     },
     "obj2":{  
        "id":2,
        "title":"Title2"
     },
     "obj3":{  
        "id":3,
        "title":"Title3"
     }
  }; 

  $scope.testArray = [];
  Object.keys(testObj).forEach(function(key) {
    $scope.testArray.push(testObj[key]);
  });
  // Now you can use $scope.testArray as a normal array in your view.
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="obj in testArray | orderBy: title: reverse" ng-bind="obj.title"></li>
  </ul>
  <button type="button" ng-model="reverse" ng-click="reverse = !reverse">Reverse order</button>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note:** Doing this way, you just need to *parse* your objects to array once, instead of doing this everytime when needs to sort.

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/orderBy/notarray

I hope it helps!

**EDIT:**

I noticed you're using this construction:

```
ng-style="$index % 2 === 0 && {'background-color': '#ffffff'} || $index % 2 === 1 && {'background-color': '#f9f9f9'}"
```

You can simplify your life simply using the native [*special-properties*](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), then you can have something like this:

```
ng-style="$even && {'background-color': '#ffffff'} || $odd && {'background-color': '#f9f9f9'}"
```

**Note:** Change your ng-repeat to your `<tr>` tag.